# Is there any open source tools available for chimeric sequence detection?

Tags: bioinformatics, genome, sequencing

Is there any tools for detecting and removing chimeric sequences from 16s,WGS,WTS sequences other than USearch. The alternative should be open source so that it can be used for commercial purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There is `http://qiime.org/tutorials/chimera_checking.html`
As I understand from your question this would sufice.

Answer (score 0):

[VSEARCH](https://github.com/torognes/vsearch) is another open source answer to USEARCH.